Create an HTML/Angular multi select listbox
I need to create a multi select listbox with a keyboard navigation. So far, I have the following HTML template:
<div>
 <div
    *ngFor="let tag of tags; let index=index"
    [class.selectedRow]="rowIsSelected(tag.id)"
    (click)="onRowClick(tag.id, $event)">
    <span>{{ tag.text }}</span>
 </div>
</div>

Is there a way of adding a keyboard navigation (up and down mostly) to the above code?

You can use (keydown.arrowup), and (keydown.arrowdown) to respond to events, but set a tabindex on the div or it won't fire the event... i.e. tabindex="{index}".  You might also consider using an already built control for this... the browser's <select multiple, or ng-multiselect...  or maybe even checkboxes?

Not familiar with ng-multiselect. Is it a part of Angular Material?

yes, https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection

you can try with using (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)" event in html
<div class="menu-container"

(click)="menuOpened = true" (mouseenter)="menuOpened = true" 

(mouseleave)="menuOpened = false" (keydown)="onKeyDown($event)">

<span #menuTrigger tabindex="0">Menu</span>

</div>

test.component.ts
@ViewChild('menuTrigger', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) 

private menuTrigger : ElementRef;



public onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

switch (event.key) {

case 'Escape':

  this.menuOpened = false;

  this.menuTrigger.nativeElement.focus();

  break;

case 'Enter':

    this.menuOpened = true;

    // make sure that the menu is open before setting focus

    setTimeout(() => this.multiLevelDropDown.setFocusOnFirstMenuItem(), 1);

    break;

case 'Tab':

  if (this.menuOpened) {

    this.menuOpened = false;

  }
  break;

 }

}

